# Where did Messages go on AndroidStudio 3.2

Tags: android, android-studio

It's become so second nature that I can't even remember in which window the compile time errors were showing, but I've just updated to Studio 3.2 and I can't seem to find the Messages window or something similar to it.

I'm looking for that panel in which the compile time errors were showing up and you could click on each one and it would jump to that specific file. The only thing I can find is this thing below, on which it's very inefficient to keep expanding the tree and looking at each individual error. Also, clicking on the error items doesn't jump to the file, only if I press Return on my keyboard.

Is this really the replacement of the previous panel? It's very, very inefficient

[image]

**EDIT**

If I click the icon on the left side of the Build panel it displays them as below, but as text ... ! There must be a better way ... isn't there ?

[image]

Comment: why don't you check log cat option in bottom tabs?

Answer (score 0):

you can see log output in Logcat from tool windows Bar or short key(Alt + 6) 
and select **Error** Filter also i prefer search **main** word in error filter. 
most of time problem appear in top sentences and you can go to location by clicking on link .

Comment: uhm..wait...isn't the LogCat for runtime exceptions only? Does it now display the compile-time ones as well ?! o.O

Comment: both of them are possible .

Comment: how ?!  I looked a bit but can't find how to see the compile ones

Comment: not separate place , you can see runtime error or compile error in logcat .